# How to have Bash set -x only apply to the very next command without creating child processes and without calling set +x

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is limited to Bash only, and the answer needs to work on all Bash versions without exception.

I do this now:

```
op1
(set -x; op2)
op3
```

and it does what I expect: The `op1` is not transcribed, the `op2` **is** transcribed, and then `op3` is not.  And this has the feature that if "code wedging" occurs whereby op2 has a lot of lines of text, I do not have to remember to call `set +x` later on, because of the scoping with the parentheses. I do not want `set +x` to *also* get transcribed, either as it clutters up the output.

So, how do I do the above without having to explicitly call `set +x`? I've tried curly brackets but they don't "undo" the `set -x` like the parentheses do.

Comment: "All bash versions without exception"? It's easy to test something back to 3.2, which is the oldest release in use today. 1.x, not so much.

Comment: It is not easy, unless one has easy access to those old versions. I do see your [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65240685/257924), though!

Comment: BTW, there _is_ an `evalbot` daemon in the Freenode IRC network that has a wide variety of ancient bash versions in a VM snapshot one can ask it to run commands in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except in the case of modern bash 4.x with the off-by-default BASH_XTRACEFD feature in active use, the following will work fine:

```
logged_cmd() {
  local rc=0
  set -x
  "$@"
  { { rc=$?; set +x; }; } 2>/dev/null
  return "$rc"
}

op1
logged_cmd op2
op3
```

Adding support for cases where BASH_XTRACEFD is in use (to cause `set -x` logs to go somewhere other than stderr) will require using bash 4.1+ features, which has been explicitly disallowed in the question.

Comment: Very helpful answer.  Could you clarify why the extra layer of curly brackets is required here? On my current Bash version, if I take out the outer two curly brackets, it still seems to work. E.g., this: `{ rc=$?; set +x; } 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @bgoodr, I hate to be contributing to the cargo-cult problem in shell, but alas, I don't remember the details as to exactly when that's necessary.

Comment: Got it. So, for now, until someone can share a reference to a "proof" that the additional braces are needed, I'm not going to include them.  I've scoured repeatedly for any mention of the extra brace usage, and came up empty.

Comment: _nod_. Honestly, I wouldn't have included them if you hadn't insisted on answers that work for every possible version of bash; there are quite a lot of historical bugs that only impact a small version range -- some of the prophylactic practices I follow are applicable only to the first minor version to introduce native regex support, f/e, even though those versions aren't likely to be in common use anywhere.

Comment: Yep.  Reconsidering that decision of mine: I spent some time in a massive scan of hundreds of Linux hosts I have access to (and it is not a complete scan, as I don't have direct/quick access to all of them, as many of them block SSH connections), and range of bash versions range from `4.1.2(1)-release` to `4.4.19(1)-release`.  So I might have gotten away with stating a minimum version of 4.1.x up front in the description. Had I not been as strict, I speculate that I would not have gotten as well-thought-out response as your answer here.